# Why Apache Mahout naive bayes classifications scores are negative

Tags: mahout

I trained a naive bayes classifier using mahout, and used it on some test set. the resulting classes are correct (acceptable) but all of the scores are negative.

Example:

*Tweet: I hope you are doing good*

Bad: -51.227871491950815

Good: -49.90454258543385

**Best => Good**